# How to create moderated chat, then add contact to the chat created

Tags: .net, vb.net, skype4com

as seen in the title, I am trying to create a moderated chat and then add a contact to the chat created.

I tried this to add someone to a group chat (something like this):

```
For Each chat As Chat In Skypattach.BookmarkedChats
If chat.Name = "#my-skype/$baf1ad******" Then
    msg.Chat.SendMessage("Please wait while we add you!)
    chat.SendMessage("/add " & "contact-to-add")
End If
Next
```

But I need to specify the chat name, so that doesn't work for now. I got an idea I don't know how to do, and don't know if its possible, but also is there a way to create the moderated chat, then get the chat name of the chat created? That could fix my problem... If there's any fix to my problem please tell me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suprised that the line `chat.SendMessage("/add " & "contact-to-add")` works in the first place, as I get errors when I use it.  So instead, I used a subroutine to add the new member(s) in via a UserCollection object.  When you want to add new members, add to the UserCollection, and then pass that to the AddMembers() subroutine.

As for the chat name itself, you don't need it.  If you create the chat on the spot, you assign it to a Chat variable.

```
Imports SKYPE4COMLib


Public Class Form1

Dim skype As Skype
Dim uc As UserCollection
Dim chat As Chat

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    skype = New Skype()
    skype.Attach(7, True)
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    uc = New UserCollection()    'Hold the users in a UserCollection obj
    uc.Add(skype.User("echo123"))
    uc.Add(skype.User("otherperson_123123123123121625"))

    chat = skype.CreateChatMultiple(uc)  'Create the chat with the 2 users
    chat.OpenWindow()
    chat.Topic = "test"
    chat.SendMessage("test")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'CHECK TO MAKE SURE YOU DON'T TRY AND ADD SAME PERSON TWICE!
    'For some reason, attempting to do so causes errors.
    For Each r As User In uc
        If TextBox1.Text = r.Handle Then
            Return
        End If
    Next
    skype.SendMessage(TextBox1.Text, "Please wait while we add you!")
    uc.Add(skype.User(TextBox1.Text))
    chat.AddMembers(uc)
End Sub
End Class
```

I hope you that this answers your question and is useful to you.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't that active. I will test it and tell you the result :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help!